# Add data point in Health app

Tags: ios, health.app

Is there a way to add a data point for steps and workouts in the Apple Health app in iOS 10? I cannot find it.

Answer (score 2):

From the main screen (Health Data), tap on Activity, then the item you want to add a data point for (Steps, Walking + Running Distance, etc.)

From there, tap on the + in the upper-right hand corner and you can enter a new data point.